# Azure DataFactory SSIS IR memory failure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl, azure-data-factory

I followed the tutorial in the below link and created a Azure SSIS IR and deployed the package of SSIS *[Tutorial - deploy SSIS packages Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure)*

i am receiving following error while executing a package

> **ErrorCode**: "2400"
> **Message**: "Your package execution did not succeed for execution ID: 86"
> **FailureType**: "UserError"
> **Target**: "My SProc Activity"

When looked in to the catalog.operations i am seeing data flow erros

> Data Flow Task:Error: The system reports 71 percent memory load. There are 30064300032 bytes of physical memory with 8547852288 bytes free. There are 140737488224256 bytes of virtual memory with 140686702383104 bytes free. The paging file has 34359267328 bytes with 12840960 bytes free.
>
> Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Sort 3" (735) failed with error code 0x80004005 while processing input "Sort Input" (738). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  Data Flow Task:Error: The input buffer could not be cloned. An out-of-memory condition occurred or there was an internal error.  Data Flow Task:Error: The input buffer could not be cloned. An out-of-memory condition occurred or there was an internal error.

I am using P4 Sql server

```
StartedLocation : EastUS
NodeSize : Standard_D4_v2
NodeCount : 4
MaxParallelExecutionsPerNode : 4
```

It is 1GB file sorted to make some. I wanted to process a 22 files of such 1GB. Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: You could try with a bigger VM, see if you get the same problem?  eg `Standard_A8_v2`

Comment: I read that in the public preview of Data factory V2 they support until Standard_D4_v2

Comment: I have the same issue right now in v2 with a 64GB runtime. Failing with memory errors, but there is loads of memory free (50GB)

Comment: ... and it appears that if we use a cache column data type of DT_WSTR(100) it fails but if we use a cache column type of DT_WSTR(10) it does not